# Exception thrown when WndProc is overloaded

Tags: .net, winforms, exception, f#, wndproc

I'm trying to get at the Close event of the .NET WebBrowser type, which doesn't seem to work out of the box. (**EDIT:** This event is emitted when the `window.close()` call is issued in a script running in the browser.)

One solution I've seen is to [extend the `WebBrowser` class and `override` the `WndProc` method](http://blogs.artinsoft.net/Mrojas/archive/2009/05/21/Extended-WebBrowser-Control-Series-WebBrowser-Control-and-windowClose%28%29.aspx).

My extension code is as follows:

```
type internal ExtendedBrowser () = class
    inherit System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser()

    let WM_PARENTNOTIFY : int = 0x0210
    let WM_DESTROY      : int = 0x0002

    let closed : Event<unit> = new Event<unit>()

    do ()

    [<System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")>]
    override this.WndProc (msg : Message byref) =
        match msg.Msg with
        | wm when wm = WM_PARENTNOTIFY ->
            if (not base.DesignMode) && (msg.WParam.ToInt32() = WM_DESTROY)
            then closed.Trigger()
            base.DefWndProc(ref msg)
        | _ ->
            base.WndProc(ref msg)

    member this.Closed = closed.Publish
end
```

This ends up causing an exception to be thrown when an instance of the type is accessed:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Unable to get the window handle for the 'ExtendedBrowser' control. Windowless ActiveX controls are not supported. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Error creating window handle.
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle(CreateParams cp)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserBase.DoVerb(Int32 verb)
   at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserBase.TransitionFromRunningToInPlaceActive()

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserBase.TransitionFromRunningToInPlaceActive()

   at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserBase.TransitionUpTo(AXState state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.get_AxIWebBrowser2()
   at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.PerformNavigate2(Object& URL, Object& flag
s, Object& targetFrameName, Object& postData, Object& headers)
   at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.Navigate(String urlString)
   at [PRODUCT].Application.WebBrowser..ctor() in C:\[PATH]\WebBrowser.fs:line 107
   at Program.Main.main(String[] args) in C:\[PATH]\Program.fs:line 79
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Currently it's erroring on a call to `Navigate("about:blank")` (the first access of the instance after its construction). I can comment out the `WndProc` override and things work fine (besides missing the close event).

Someone said you had to [put the security attribute on the `WndProc` override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010296/net-4-0-accessviolationexception-and-wndproc) so I did that and it didn't fix things.

Someone else said you can [disable the DEP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12000538/225292), but I tried and it didn't let me exempt the EXE.

An instance of the extension is being created in a wrapper for the browser (also called WebBrowser) and an instance of this is being created in my `main`, which is runing in an [STAThread] (which also seems to be required).

Does anyone know what could be going wrong?

(What I'm really after is a way to get notification of the close event, so if someone knows an alternate route to that I'd be happy to hear it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a post where someone else had had the same [problem overriding the WndProc method in F#](http://cs.hubfs.net/topic/None/57539), and the solution there worked for me; working code is as follows:

```
type ExtendedWebBrowser () = class
    inherit System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser()

    let WM_PARENTNOTIFY : int = 0x0210
    let WM_DESTROY      : int = 0x0002

    let closed : Event<unit> = new Event<unit>()

    do ()

    override this.WndProc (msg : Message byref) =
        match msg.Msg with
        | wm when wm = WM_PARENTNOTIFY ->
            if (not base.DesignMode) && (msg.WParam.ToInt32() = WM_DESTROY)
            then closed.Trigger()
            base.DefWndProc(&msg)
        | _ ->
            base.WndProc(&msg)

    member this.Closed = closed.Publish
end
```

It seems that F# treats `ref` a bit differently than C#: Doing some reading on [Parameters and Arguments in F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx) -- see the *Passing by Reference* section -- it seems that the `ref` call copies its argument and uses that copy as the value for the referential cell; so, what I had been passing was a reference cell containing a copy of the contents of `msg` rather than a reference to the original. The address-of operator (`&`) gets the address of the value, so that's what was needed for the arguments to the `DefWndProc` and `WndProc` methods instead of wrapping them in `ref`s.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be notified when the `WebBrowser` control is closed, you might be able to create an instance of the normal `WebBrowser` class and add an event handler to the `HandleDestroyed` event -- it's fired when the form/control containing your instance of `WebBrowser` is closed.

If that doesn't work, you can try casting the `Parent` property to `Form` and hooking the `FormClosing` event; see here for an example of both techniques: [HandleDestroyed event in userControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657862/handledestroyed-event-in-usercontrol)

Comment: Sadly, the parent form won't be closing when this event is emitted  -- I'm looking to capture a call in the browser to the `window.close()` method, after which I'll remove the browser instance from the form. I'll search and see if there's anything else down this avenue that might be of use; thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: No problem. You might also try the `Timer`-based approach suggested here: [window.close() freezes .NET 2.0 WebBrowser Control in Windows Form application](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2008/04/23/window-close-freezes-net-2-0-webbrowser-control-in-windows-form-application.aspx?Redirected=true). It's a followup post to the "extension"-based approach you linked to in your question.

Comment: I found what the problem was! (See my answer.) -- I had seen that post about the timer-based approach but it hadn't occurred to me to use it since I'm not using .NET 2.0 and wasn't experiencing freezing. Thanks again for your input!